# Why can't I install noise (music player) in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, sound, software-installation, noise

I followed these steps to install the music player `noise` in my Ubuntu 13.10.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemequ/sqlheavy
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install noise
```

But, the terminal shows me `No se ha podido localizar el paquete noise` (Could not locate the noise package, yes, my Ubuntu is in Spanish).

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the ppa page on launchpad.net, you'll see that the noise package is only built for Trusty (14.04), not 13.10:

https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/daily/+packages?field.name_filter=noise

[image]